# Receiving an error when attempting to set a data retention policy on a contact builder data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I'm attempting to implement a data retention policy on data extension and I'm receiving the following error: `"Can't implement data retention policy right now. Try again later."`

The data extension is at a little over 13,000 records, non-sendable, and 18.95 MB.  Unsure why Marketing Cloud won't allow me to set the policy.  Please advise.

Comment: is this a shared DE and are you doing this in email studio or contact builder?

Comment: It's a shared DE and I was able to update the retention policy in the parent BU.  Thanks for the help.